# Compare two panda data frames to find word count

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas data frames named as '`frequentList`' and '`fulltext`'. I want to create a new column for `fulltext` `dataset`, that returns word count, matched with fulltext '`text_value`' column (contains string list) and frequentList '`unique_values`'(contains word list).

This is my code:

```
unique_words = frequentList ['unique_values'].tolist()

pattern = r'\b{}\b'.format('|'.join(unique_words ))

fulltext['count'] = fulltext.text_value.str.count(pattern )
```

but this code generates an error

> raise source.error("unbalanced parenthesis") re.error: unbalanced
> parenthesis at position 3194

However if I change unique_words as follows,

```
unique_words = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3']
```

This code works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your dataframe `frequentList`, you have a word with ')':

```
>>> frequentList
  unique_values
0         word1
1         word2
2         word3
3         word)
```

So you have to apply `re.escape` before:

```
import re

unique_words = frequentList['unique_values'].apply(re.escape).tolist()
print(unique_words)

# Output
['word1', 'word2', 'word3', 'word\\)']
```